# Screen freezes when I click on a button(Xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to make a page where when I click on a button, it retrieves data and shows an activity indicator while it waits.

But when click on the button, it freezes.
I binded the isVisible Property of the button and set him to false when clicked. When it's done, it sets the isVisible to true, but the screen still freezes.

And then i try with this code

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  VidljivoDugmePretrazi = false;
});
```

But didnt work, and the same situation on login page and work. Can someone help me, or have someone experience with this situation? Thank you.

Comment: can you post complete code? n btw whats `VidljivoDugmePretrazi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your asynchronous method from the main thread and then update your isVisible Property in your viewmodel.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(YourAsyncMethod);
private async void YourAsyncMethod()
{
    //...
    VidljivoDugmePretrazi = true;
    try
    {
      await GetDataAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      //...
    }
    finally
    {
       VidljivoDugmePretrazi = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this,i have method which return void,and cant await void method,how to resolve this? I try with await Task.Delay(5000); and work....

Comment: I success with this code: await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, _datumVrednost).Wait(); 
               
            }); Thank you.

Comment: if you can't await void method, then you can use private async Task YourAsyncMethod...

Comment: This is terrible advice... this can cause you to lock your UI... you should only use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread in the areas that you absolutely need to... I should add that for people using Prism as is indicated... you should never be using the static Device class but rather the IDeviceService should be injected via DI into your ViewModel

Comment: @Dan Siegel: is it possible you give more details about your recommandation for us to gain more understanding?